# How to call UI-method from other class thread?

Tags: c#, wpf

My UDP-listner class thread works well, but how can I pass the recData string to my UI method UpdateCommand? I used the Dispatcher in UpdateCommand but how do I call the method in ListenForUDPPackages()? I tried several calls but probably I don't see the forrest for the trees. Any help iwould be great! Thanks Klaus

```
namespace SoftEKA
{
   
    
    public delegate void OnDataReceivedHandler(string newData);
    public class UDPListener
    {
        private int portToListen = 5001;
        private volatile bool listening;
        Thread UDPListeningThread;
        public string recData;
        public event OnDataReceivedHandler DataReceived;

        // constructor
        public UDPListener()
        {
            this.listening = false;
        }

        // starts the UDPListener-Thread
        public void StartListener(int exceptedMessageLength)
        {
            if (!this.listening)
            {
                UDPListeningThread = new Thread(ListenForUDPPackages);
                this.listening = true;
                UDPListeningThread.Start();
            }
        }
        // stops the UDPListener-Thread
        public void StopListener()
        {
            this.listening = false;
        }
 
        // receives incoming UDP-Messages
        public void ListenForUDPPackages()
        {      
            UdpClient listener = null;
            try
            {
                listener = new UdpClient(portToListen);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                //do nothing
            }

            if (listener != null)
            {
                {
                    IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, portToListen);
                    //MainWindow MW = new MainWindow();

                    try
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            // received message as array of byte
                            byte[] data = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);

                            Console.WriteLine($"Received broadcast from {groupEP} :");
                            Console.WriteLine($"{Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length)}");
                            recData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
                            MessageBox.Show(recData);

                             ------>  here!! Calling the UI-method UpdateCommand(recData)

                            if (DataReceived != null)
                                DataReceived(recData);
                            else
                                Console.WriteLine("Null ausgeloest");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (SocketException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        listener.Close();
                        Console.WriteLine("Done listening for UDP broadcast");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Users\Klaus\Music\beep.wav");

        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.178.255"), 5000);

        UDPListener listener = new UDPListener();


    
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listener.StartListener(1024);

        }


       public void UpdateCommand(string data)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { Command.Text = data; });
        }
```

Comment: This is not C++, no delegate or ref keywords in C++, maybe C++/CLI?

Comment: I think this is actually C#, can't see any handles in the code and in CLI/C++ it is Console::WriteLine();

Comment: This is definitely not C++. I don't get how it is possible to select a tag randomly and expect to receive an answer as if it didn't matter :D

Comment: Sorry, wrong tag. It is c# in WPF.

Comment: UDPListener is in the wpf app?

Comment: Yes, but I put it in its own class. The thread is startet in the contructor of MainWindow. All worked well, but I dont' know how to pass the receiced UDP message to show it in my TextBox named Command. in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Since UpdateCommand is public, you can cast the app's main window and call the method.

```
var mw = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
mw.UpdateCommand(recData);
```

If UDPListener is running in it's own thread then mainwindow has thread affinity so you will need to use dispatcher and invoke or invokeasync on that.

Personally, I would make that ListenForUDPPackages an async task and do:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync((Action)(() =>
{
    var mw = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
    mw.UpdateCommand(recData);
}));
```

Assuming mainwindow is up and running before you start udp listener and you don't do anything weird ( and ill advised IMO ) with a second sta thread, there should be just the one dispatcher in your app.

MainWindow is itself a control so you could alternatively explicitly use the dispatcher on that. Which will be the same one as application.current.

```
mw.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync((Action)(() =>
{
    var mw = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
    mw.UpdateCommand(recData);
}));
```

Personally, I prefer application.current.

Comment: Thank You so much!! I was about to give up. At the moment the udp listener is startet in the contructor of MainWindow. I'm not sure whether this means that MainWindow is up and running completly. Is there anything wrong with starting the listenern in the contructor? So, I'm using your first suggestion.